# Favicons used in HTML

Tags: html, favicon

New to development and learning..

Do you have to download the favicon to your computer in order to reference in your HTML code OR can you reference image directly from web?

Comment: You can download or using image URL you can do it

Comment: Please search in google and share sample code that you tried to get response in stackoverflow otherwise you will end up getting down votes

Comment: I am looking for clarification not votes per say...I have been researching Google and it's slightly confusing

Answer (score 0):

The image must be served from a Web Server. It could be from your own server or any other web page.

For example, assuming the image is in your main folder you can add it with:
    `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>`

**Note:** *Displaying an image on a website by linking to another website is called hotlinking and should only be done when the website explicitly allows it.*